# Is there a way I can use SDL_RenderClear() without clearing everything?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, renderer

I have some homegrown code to draw a circle in SDL2 (It's slow). Each time I want to update the window, I have to call SDL_RenderClear() and redraw the same circle. Is there any way I can avoid clearing the circle but still clear the rest of the screen to allow me to draw everything else.

The circle has to be drawn over the top of everything else.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oATkz.jpg

I could draw the circle each time over the rest of the image, but that takes about 500ms.

Comment: I imagine it takes 500 ms in order to *build* the circle. What if you just create a texture with the circle and directly draw the texture? It should not take too much time to draw just one single texture.

Comment: @BiagioFesta I thought of using an image for the circle but I figured there must be some method to do it without.

I think my best shot for now is using a more efficient circle algorithm.

Comment: What I meant is to create a `SDL_Surface`. Perform pixel operations in order to build your amazing circle image (you can checkout SDL_gfx for drawing primitive on surfaces). After you can convert the result into a single texture and draw the entire system with a single draw operation